# Cannot read property 'width' of undefined (style.width)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Alright, so I got following component (uses typescript but should be self-explanatory) for `ImageBackground`. (this is react-native)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, ImageURISource } from "react-native";
import { width as deviceW } from "../services/device";

type Props = {
  width: number;
  ratio: number;
  unit: "px" | "%";
  source: ImageURISource;
};

class AspectRatioBackground extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { width, ratio, unit, ...props } = this.props;
    let w = width;
    let h = width * ratio;
    if (unit === "%") {
      w = deviceW * (width / 100);
      h = deviceW * (width / 100) * ratio;
    }
    console.log(w, h);
    return <ImageBackground style={{ width: w, height: h }} {...props} />;
  }
}

export default AspectRatioBackground;
```

and it is being used like this

```
    <AspectRatioBackground
      source={pressed ? activeBackgroundUrl : backgroundUrl}
      width={55}
      unit="%"
      ratio={0.2946}
    >
      <View pointerEvents="none">
        <String>{children}</String>
      </View>
    </AspectRatioBackground>
```

That console log returns correct number values i.e. `100` and `200`, but for some reason, I am getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

> This error is located at:
>       in ImageBackground (at AspectRatioBackground.js:25)
>       in AspectRatioBackground (at Button.js:61)
>       in TouchableWithoutFeedback (at Button.js:60)
>       in Button (at SignInEmailPage.js:22)
>       in SignInEmailPage (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(SignInEmailPage))
>       in withRouter(SignInEmailPage) (created by Route)
>       in Route (at _Onboarding.js:44)
>       in Switch (at _Onboarding.js:43)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>       in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at OnboardingRouteAnimation.js:33)
>       in OnboardingRouteAnomation (at _Onboarding.js:42)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>       in View (at ImageBackground.js:68)
>       in ImageBackground (created by Styled(ImageBackground))
>       in Styled(ImageBackground) (at _Onboarding.js:32)
>       in Onboarding (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(Onboarding))
>       in withRouter(Onboarding) (at index.js:20)
>       in LayoutIndex (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(LayoutIndex))
>       in withRouter(LayoutIndex) (at index.js:13)
>       in Router (created by MemoryRouter)
>       in MemoryRouter (at NativeRouter.js:11)
>       in NativeRouter (at index.js:12)
>       in Provider (at index.js:11)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

Comment: What's your `react-native` version ? Seems that `ImageBackground` had some trouble when wrapped by `Touchables`, you could try to use `Image` to do your component like [ImageBackground component do](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js).

Comment: This is rn 0.53, using image like that throws an error and asks to use `ImageBackground`

Comment: It works fine in version `0.55.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a `style` prop to `ImageBackground` (even an empty one like `<ImageBackground style={{}}.../>`) solves the problem.

This is because the [internals of the component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js#L100) is trying to read `width` and `height` from the (flattened) style prop. Thus the "cannot read ... of undefined"

The [documentation for this component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) states

> Note that you must specify some width and height style attributes.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the solution. How and why is beyond me.